# Almacenar ficheros de un directorio en array

Tags: c#, rutas

Tengo que almacenar los ficheros de un directorio en un array y luego recorrerme ese array.

```
System.IO.DriveInfo dirOrigen = new System.IO.DriveInfo(ruta1);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = dirOrigen.RootDirectory;

System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirOrigenNames = dirOrigenInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

for (int i=0;i<fileDirOrigenNames.GetLength;i++ )
{
...
}
```

De momento tengo este código, me da error en el `for` con `fileDirOrigenNames.GetLength`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que provienes de Java. `fileDirOrigenNames` es un array de `System.IO.FileInfo`.Para consultar el tamaño de un array en C# tienes dos opciones: la propiedad `Length` o el método `GetLength` que necesita recibir un parámetro con la dimensión de la que quieres obtener el tamaño. Intenta esto:

```
for (int i=0;i<fileDirOrigenNames.Length;i++)
{...}
```

o esto

```
for (int i=0;i<fileDirOrigenNames.GetLength(0);i++)
{...}
```

Comment: En realidad si existe el método `GetLength` que devuelve el tamaño de la dimensión del Array que recibe como argumento. Generalmente se utiliza en arrays multidimensionales aunque se puede utilizar en unidimensionales con índice 0: `fileDirOrigenNames.GetLength(0)` lo que a efectos sería equivalente a acceder al valor de la propiedad `Length`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @AsierVillanueva. Como lo normal es usar la propiedad `Length`, siempre olvido el método que en realidad se usa mas en arrays multidimensionales. Gracias por aclararlo, he editado mi respuesta :)

Comment: muchas gracias a los dos, me ha servido de mucho, un saludo!